# Linq left outer join not returning results

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to perform a left outer join on two tables based on the model on the picture[image: Database Model]

I'm using the following linq query:

```
var query = from u in Context.Set<CpcUnidadProceso>()
            join p in Context.Set<CpcParadasPrevistasUnidad>()
                on u.IdCpcUnidadesProceso equals p.IdCpcUnidadesProceso
                into g
            from result in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
            where u.RefineriaArea.IdTipoArea == filters.IdTipoArea &&
            (result.FechaParada >= filters.Fecha || result == null) && (result.FechaArranque <= filters.Fecha || result == null)
            select
                new CpcPrevisionParadasUnidadesDto
                {
                    IdCpcUnidadesProceso = u.IdCpcUnidadesProceso,
                    CodigoUnidadProceso = u.CodUnidadProceso,
                    DescripcionUnidadProceso = u.Nombre,
                    IdCpcPrevisionParadasUnidadesDto = result == null ? 0 : result.IdCpcParadasPrevistasUnidades,
                    FechaParada = result == null ? null : result.FechaParada,
                    FechaArranque = result == null ? null : result.FechaArranque,
                    Observaciones = result == null ? null : result.Observaciones
                };
```

But the results are not as expected, it's not returning results when there is a record with FechaParada and/or FechaArranque not null.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem to be caused by the following `where` condition:

```
(result.FechaParada >= filters.Fecha || result == null) && (result.FechaArranque <= filters.Fecha || result == null)
```

First off, it might not be essential for SQL queries, but it's always a good practice to first check the `null` condition, so the above can be reduced to

```
(result == null || (result.FechaParada >= filters.Fecha && result.FechaArranque <= filters.Fecha))
```

Even better, the filtering on the right side of the `left outer join` should be performed **before** the join (for left side or `inner join` it really doesn't matter):

```
from u in Context.Set<CpcUnidadProceso>()
join p in Context.Set<CpcParadasPrevistasUnidad>()
    .Where(x => x.FechaParada >= filters.Fecha && x.FechaArranque <= filters.Fecha)
on u.IdCpcUnidadesProceso equals p.IdCpcUnidadesProceso
into g
from result in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
where u.RefineriaArea.IdTipoArea == filters.IdTipoArea
// ...
```

In all the cases, you have to check if you really have a data satisfying the `FechaParada >= filters.Fecha && FechaArranque <= filters.Fecha` condition.

Comment: You save my day. Just using the first part of your answer it works like a charm. Thanks

Comment: @IvanStoev But in the second part of your answer where are you checking if the result == null?

Comment: @nam Since the whole filter has been applied before doing the join, there is not need to check for result == null in the where clause. Basically (right == null || some_condition(right)) is needed only if you use `where` after the join.

Comment: @IvanStoev But then, in your second solution, are we not ignoring the very definition of Left Outer Join? In the `where clause` we're only taking the rows that are joined on both sides.

Comment: @nam It's still a left outer join. The problem with applying filter after the join operation w/o taking into account that right side can be null effectively turns left outer join into a inner join. While applying the right side filter in advance and the doing left outer join give you the correct result w/o the need of null logic.